# Adding git branch on the Bash command prompt

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu

I tried adding the git branch I'm currently working on (checked-out) on the bash prompt without success..  (**while keeping my current path which shows the active directory/file** intact)
I have a .bashrc file on my home, but I also saw many people mentioning the .profile file..

Comment: i think this would be better asked in the unix/linux exchange.

Comment: I've tried like 10 different how-tos, some of them worked but I got the git branch and lost the working directory/path I had before..

Comment: Git 1.9.3+ brings an interesting way to display the branch: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716445/6309)

Comment: Thanks VonC! Using this one since a couple of months now, great!

Comment: @cole busby apparently not.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos four years sure showed me :p

Answer (score 250, accepted):

### git 1.9.3 or later: use `__git_ps1`

Git provides a shell script called [`git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), which includes a function `__git_ps1` that

> prints text to add to bash PS1 prompt (includes branch name)

Its most basic usage is:

```
$ __git_ps1
(master)
```

It also takes an optional format string:

```
$ __git_ps1 'git:[%s]'
git:[master]
```

#### How to Get It

First, copy the file to somewhere (e.g. `~/.git-prompt.sh`).

Option 1: use an existing copy on your filesystem.  Example (Mac OS X 10.15):

```
$ find / -name 'git-prompt.sh' -type f -print -quit 2>/dev/null
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
```

Option 2: Pull the script [from GitHub](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh).

Next, add the following line to your `.bashrc/.zshrc`:

```
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
```

Finally, change your `PS1` to call `__git_ps1` as command-substitution:

Bash:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

Zsh:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST ; PS1='[%n@%m %c$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

#### git < 1.9.3

But note that only git 1.9.3 (May 2014) [or later](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/how-can-i-update-to-a-newer-version-of-git-using-apt-get/170831#170831) allows you to *safely* display that branch name(!)

See [commit 8976500](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8976500cbbb13270398d3b3e07a17b8cc7bff43f) by [Richard Hansen (`richardhansen`)](https://github.com/richardhansen):

> Both bash and zsh subject the value of PS1 to **parameter expansion**, **command substitution**, and arithmetic expansion.

> Rather than include the raw, unescaped branch name in `PS1` when running in two- or
> three-argument mode, construct `PS1` to reference a variable that holds the branch name.

> Because the shells do not recursively expand, this avoids arbitrary code execution by specially-crafted branch names such as

```
'$(IFS=_;cmd=sudo_rm_-rf_/;$cmd)'.
```

What devious mind would name a branch like that? ;) ([Beside a Mom as in xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/))

#### More Examples

[still_dreaming_1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172274/still-dreaming-1) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883416/adding-git-branch-on-the-bash-command-prompt/24716445?noredirect=1#comment54332815_24716445):

> This seems to work great if you want a color prompt with `xterm` (in my `.bashrc`):

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\03‌​3[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1)\$ '
```

> Everything is a different color, including the branch.

In  in Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1) \$ '
```

---

As noted by [J'e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2601293/je) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883416/adding-git-branch-on-the-bash-command-prompt/24716445?noredirect=1#comment130011242_24716445)

> ### Ubuntu
>
> Modify PS1 assignments in your `bashrc` with,
>
> ```
> PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\033[0;32m$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\033[0m\$ '
>
> # ---AND--- 
>
> PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\$ '
> ```

Comment: how you can set the prompt to current git branch when you are actually in a git repo. So if you are in a normal directory it shows normal prompt.

Comment: @ZubairAlam by setting the PS1 variable in your .bashrc, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: This makes my colors go away in my terminal. I am using Linux Mint 17.2 and I downloaded the newest git-prompt.sh file from the git repository. But my git version is only 1.9.1 because that is the version Mint is on for some reason...

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 you can upgrade or compile git very easily though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the tip! I am on the latest version of git now, 2.6.2. I also made sure to copy the .git-prompt.sh file from that version. I am happy to be on the latest version of git now. However, this still makes my terminal start up without colors :(

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 is this a classic bash terminal? Do you have `git config --global color.ui` set to `always`?

Comment: This seems to work great if you want a color a color prompt with xterm (in by .bashrc): `PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1)\$'` Everything is a different color, including the branch.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I added and it really works except, when I go to a repository it also shows this error: `Usage: core.py [options]

core.py: error: no such option: -n`

Comment: That PS1 I posted no longer displays correctly for me in Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit, but this does: `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1) \$ '`

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 Thank you for the feedback (again): I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Current master is at https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh - I think we should link to that in the answer, in case an exploit is found in the future? Also: I had to escape the $ and " in my PS1 line, but that's probably due to its complexity.

Comment: @ArchimedesMP Good point: I have included the latest master version in this (now 5 years old answer)

Comment: For **Ubuntu**, there is a PS1 assignment section in the **bashrc** inside an if statement. modify each of the PS1 assignments in your with, `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\033[0;32m$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\033[0m\$ '` **---AND---** `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\$ '`

Comment: @J'e Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 78):

Follow the steps as below: (Linux)

Edit the file `~/.bashrc`, to enter following lines at its end (In case, of Mac, file would be `~/.bash_profile`)

```
# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Now, start the new terminal window, and try entering to any git-repo. The current branch would be shown, with the prompt.

[4 More Info - MAC/Linux](http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac/)

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to change the ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bashrc on OSX.

Comment: Please see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119711/why-doesnt-mac-os-x-source-bashrc AND http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc.

Comment: For colour consider changing the "git branch" to be "git -c color.ui=always branch" in parse_git_branch above.  It has the same colour that git branch uses to highlight the current branch.

Comment: Inspired by you, but I like my working directory to be the full path (\w) with blue highlighting. Example: https://gist.github.com/rmharrison/1885ef6bbb0226eb7b42e2135d5eeca2

Comment: For MAC I had to eliminate the escape before the $(parse_git_branch) to get this to work so : `PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "`. Although I am not using 'export' in front of PS1 either.

Comment: On Mac, this worked on for `git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/ (\1)/p'  -n`

Comment: @Chris if I remove the escape before the `$` the prompt keeps displaying the branch value when the shell was initialized. Aka if I change the branch it keeps displaying the old one.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you @ndnenkov mine is still like that and works for me.  I would suspect that your `parse_git_branch()` function might have a bug, try running that command by itself on different branches to see what it returns

Comment: @Chris if I leave the escape slash before `$` it works just fine.

Comment: @ndnenkov I think it must be the 2nd part of that comment.  I'm not using 'export' before 'PS1' in my profile.  Using 'export' would require that the escape be used.

Comment: If you don't like `sed`, you can instead do `git branch -q --show-current 2>/dev/null`, which only displays the current branch with no extra characters. Note: cannot auto color, instead you need to color it manually in your PS1 expression.

Comment: you need to surround the function with "`": `parse_git_branch`

Comment: Much simpler and works in RedHat too

Answer (score 44):

1-  If you don't have *bash-completion* ... : `sudo apt-get install bash-completion`

2-  Edit your *.bashrc* file and check (or add) :

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

3-  ... before your prompt line : `export PS1='$(__git_ps1) \w\$ '`
(**__git_ps1** will show your git branch)

4-  do `source .bashrc`

**EDIT :**

Further readings : [Don’t Reinvent the Wheel](https://web.archive.org/web/20160704140739/http://ithaca.arpinum.org/2013/01/02/git-prompt.html)

Comment: this seems to be the only way it works for me using a homestead/vagrant machine

Comment: Works fine in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The "Don't Reinvent the Wheel" link is sadly broken.

Comment: @TaylorR I have restored the link.

Answer (score 39):

Here is how I configured the prompt to display Git status:

Get git-prompt script:

```
curl -o ~/.git-prompt.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
```

And customize your prompt adding the following code in your .bashrc file:

```
# Load Git functions
source ~/.git-prompt.sh

# Syntactic sugar for ANSI escape sequences
txtblk='\e[0;30m' # Black - Regular
txtred='\e[0;31m' # Red
txtgrn='\e[0;32m' # Green
txtylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow
txtblu='\e[0;34m' # Blue
txtpur='\e[0;35m' # Purple
txtcyn='\e[0;36m' # Cyan
txtwht='\e[0;37m' # White
bldblk='\e[1;30m' # Black - Bold
bldred='\e[1;31m' # Red
bldgrn='\e[1;32m' # Green
bldylw='\e[1;33m' # Yellow
bldblu='\e[1;34m' # Blue
bldpur='\e[1;35m' # Purple
bldcyn='\e[1;36m' # Cyan
bldwht='\e[1;37m' # White
unkblk='\e[4;30m' # Black - Underline
undred='\e[4;31m' # Red
undgrn='\e[4;32m' # Green
undylw='\e[4;33m' # Yellow
undblu='\e[4;34m' # Blue
undpur='\e[4;35m' # Purple
undcyn='\e[4;36m' # Cyan
undwht='\e[4;37m' # White
bakblk='\e[40m'   # Black - Background
bakred='\e[41m'   # Red
badgrn='\e[42m'   # Green
bakylw='\e[43m'   # Yellow
bakblu='\e[44m'   # Blue
bakpur='\e[45m'   # Purple
bakcyn='\e[46m'   # Cyan
bakwht='\e[47m'   # White
txtrst='\e[0m'    # Text Reset

# Prompt variables
PROMPT_BEFORE="$txtcyn\u@\h $txtwht\w$txtrst"
PROMPT_AFTER="\\n\\\$ "

# Prompt command
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "$PROMPT_BEFORE" "$PROMPT_AFTER"'

# Git prompt features (read ~/.git-prompt.sh for reference)
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE="true"
export GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE="true"
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES="true"
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS="true"
```

If you want to find out more, you can get all the dotfiles here: https://github.com/jamming/dotfiles

Comment: Best answer so far.

Comment: @Hesam You can change the `PROMPT_BEFORE` environment variable and remove the `$txtwht\w` I don't know it by heart, but I guess it does the trick

Comment: It works on my mac but shows the branch name like (master *$%=)

Comment: Those symbols resemble the state of the branch, ie: `$` means that there are stashed changes, and `=` means that the latest commit was pushed to the remote tracked branch

Answer (score 11):

For mac, this works really well: http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac/:

```
# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Answer (score 8):

```
root:~/project#  -> root:~/project(dev)#
```

add the following code to the end of your ~/.bashrc

```
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Comment: I like that this doesn't screw up the colorization when the current dir isn't part of a repo, as with other answers.

Answer (score 8):

At first, open your Bash Profile in your home directory. The easiest way to open & edit your **bash_profile** using your default editor.

For example, I open it using the VS Code using this command: code .bash_profile.

Then just paste the following codes to your Bash.

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

The function

> parse_git_branch()

will fetch the branch name & then through PS1 you can show it in your terminal.

Here,

> \u = Username
>
> @ = Static Text
>
> \h = Computer Name
>
> \w = Current Directory
>
> $ = Static Text

You can change or remove these variables for more customization.

---

If you use Git for the first time in terminal or instantly after configuration, maybe sometimes you can not see the branch name.

If you get this problem, don't worry. In that case, just make a sample repository and commit it after some changes. When the commit command will execute once, the terminal will find git branch from then.

---

[image: Screenshot: Git Branch in Terminal]

Answer (score 5):

I wanted a clean solution that appended to the existing prompt instead of replacing it.  As with other solutions, add this to the bottom of your .bashrc

```
# function
parse_git_branch() {
  if [ -n "$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
    echo ">> $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) >>"
  fi
}

# environment customization
export PS1="\$(parse_git_branch)\n$PS1"
```

This setup yields a prompt that looks like

```
>> branchname >>
user@host:~/current/path$
```

Additionally I like to add a bit of color to the prompt so it stands out better like so

```
export PS1="\e[0;36m\$(parse_git_branch)\e[0m\n$PS1"
```

which causes the name of the branch to appear in CYAN

Answer (score 2):

```
vim ~/.bash

parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $"
```

To reflect latest changes run following command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Output:-

```
chandrakant@NDL41104 ~/Chandrakant/CodeBase/LaravelApp (development) $
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [fish shell](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell) its quite straight forward.
fish is an interactive shell which comes with lots of goodies. You can install it using `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-get install fish
```

you can then change the prompt setting using

```
> fish_config 
Web config started at 'http://localhost:8001/'. Hit enter to stop.
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

now go to `http://localhost:8001/`
open the prompt tab and choose the classic + git option

[image]

Now click on the use prompt button and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]$(parse_git_branch)\n\$ '
```

Comment: Eww, really don't put naked terminal escapes in there; use `tput` like any sane person.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps to show the name of the branch of your GIT repo in ubuntu terminal:**

**step1:** open terminal and edit .bashrc using the following command.

vi .bashrc

**step2:** add the following line at the end of the .bashrc file :

```
parse_git_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/' }
```

`export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "`

**step3:** source .bashrc in the root (home) directory by doing:

/rootfolder:~$ `source .bashrc`

**Step4:** Restart and open the terminal and check the cmd. Navigate to your GIt repo directory path and you are done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple clean version that I use: [link](https://gist.github.com/kfcobrien/c75a918682c6c9b11d3aa6dedb5d3928)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check this repo: https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt
This prompt is a port of the "Informative git prompt for zsh"

via Git clone
Clone this repository to your home directory.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt.git ~/.bash-git-prompt --depth=1
```

Add to the ~/.bashrc:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh" ]; then
    GIT_PROMPT_ONLY_IN_REPO=1
    source $HOME/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ZSH I usually do:

```
export PROMPT="\$vcs_info_msg_0_"
# outputs the name of the branch like `[develop]`
```

Where you can obviously add your other stuff

Another workaround is:

```
curr_branch() {
    # get current branch
    git branch --show-current
    # outputs just the name of the branch, like `develop`
}
# bash
export PS1="\$(curr_branch)"
# zsh
export PROMPT="\$(curr_branch)"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried a small script in python that goes in a bin folder....
'gitprompt' file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, os
s = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '.git')
def cut(cmd):
    ret=''
    half=0
    record = False
    for c in cmd:
        if c == "\n":
            if not (record):
                pass
            else:
                break
        if (record) and c!="\n":
            ret = ret + c
        if c=='*':
            half=0.5
        if c==' ':
            if half == 0.5:
                half = 1
        if half == 1:
            record = True
    return ret
if (os.path.isdir(s)):
    out = subprocess.check_output("git branch",shell=True)
    print cut(out)
else:
    print "-"
```

Make it executable and stuff

Then adjust the bash prompt accordingly like :

```
\u:\w--[$(gitprompt)] \$
```