# Upgrading git from the source repository in Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, repository

I want to upgrade git using the [source repository](https://github.com/git/git) in Ubuntu. As you note, the last stable version is 2.0.2, but I have 1.9.4.

I cloned the git repo, but I'm not sure how to continue.

I want to do that in some way I can understand how to interact with the branches and tags of the repo, so I am not searching for solutions of [this type](http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/)

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.0.2 has been uploaded 3 days ago in this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

But if this isn't what you want, and you have clone the git repo, then

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev bzip2
cd /path/to/local/clone/of/git
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you, just one more question. Have the commands _./configure_, _make_, and _sudo make install_ the same functionality as: _make prefix=/usr/local all_, _sudo make prefix=/usr/local install_ ?. I founded them in [this website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-14-04) (check the part that says "if you want to upgrade ...")

Comment: @dapias yes, the `./configure` would set the `--prefix` for you, so you don't have to repeat it afterward. Type `./configure --help` for more on the various options, but generally the defaults are good.