# git status: on branch XXX Your branch is ahead of origin/YYY by 10 commits

Tags: git, git-branch

I have this message on git status:

```
# On branch YYY
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/XXX' by 10 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Branch YYY is child of branch XXX. But normally on git status I would expect:

```
# On branch YYY
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/YYY' by 10 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Git fetch does not solve the problem.
Any ideas?

Output of `git branch -avvv` (filtered):

```
* XXX                              0d64037 [origin/YYY: ahead 10] test
  remotes/origin/XXX               0d64037 test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `git branch -avvv`

Maybe `YYY` has been set to track `origin/XXX`.

You can change it with:

```
git branch branch_name -u your_new_remote/branch_name
git branch YYY -u origin/YYY

# for git older than 1.8
git branch YYY --set-upstream origin/YYY
```

You will need to push `YYY` at least once, before seeing anything about `origin/YYY` in the `git status` output.

Comment: cannot find - u option

Comment: ok I solved with:  git branch XXX --set-upstream origin/YYY and then I made a push as you suggested. you can add this to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @albanx great. `-u` is for git 1.8 or later (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309)

Comment: @albanx depending on your OS, you can upgrade easily (for instance, for Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309)

Comment: I have 1.7.1 git, so --set-upstream is the alternative

Comment: @albanx true, I have edited the answer to include the old option.