# Git pull/clone a branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need to fetch the files from just one specific branch. I have tried a couple of commands, but it ends up pulling the whole repo, instead of just the few files I need to pull to a directory from the specific branch.

*git version 1.7.1*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone a single branch in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Comment: `git clone git@bitbucket.org:name/name.git -b mv_LookbookAddition --single-branch` ends up with *error: unknown option `single-branch'*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you get an error on:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:name/name.git -b mv_LookbookAddition --single-branch
```

It means you need to 1.7.10+ (June 2012), using, for [Linux, a ppa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309) or [git-scm.com/download/mac](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) for Mac.

But you will get the full history of the branch (if that branch has been created from `master`, you will get all the commits from `master`, up until the branch starts, plus the branch commits)

You can try and combine the --depth option to get only the last commits from the branch alone

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:name/name.git -b yourBranch --single-branch --depth 10
```

That will your cloned repo a shallow repo, which is why you want a [git 2.0+ (because you can create commits and push back, from your shallow repo)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309).

See <kbd>**[explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git%20clone%20git%40bitbucket.org%3Aname%2Fname.git%20-b%20yourBranch%20--single-branch%20--depth%2010)**</kbd>.

Comment: If I do it with an updated Git version it will clone the whole repo, instead of the branch I specified.

Comment: @nicoX I confirm it only clones the selected branch. What OS and what version of Git are you using?

Comment: Latest tested with *git version 1.8.3.2* on my *Ubuntu 13.10*. My branch is on *Bitbucket*, it's not merged with the `master` branch.

Comment: @nicoX Ok. Use the ppa I mention (like https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and upgrade to 2.1.1. Clone that BitBucket repo in a separate non-existing local folder.

Comment: Updated to *2.1.1*. It's still counting all my files when cloning, instead of the branch that only contains +-30 files: `Cloning into '/home/user/test_55'...
remote: Counting objects: 19293, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9630/9630), done. Receiving objects:`

Comment: @nicoX that is a *remote* message, and it should compress and transmit only the files of your branch (with their *all* history, *all* their commits, so a bit more than ~30)

Comment: It still fetching the whole master branch and repo.

Comment: @nicoX if your branch starts from master, this is working as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand now. I just want to download the branch I specified, it's just small changes, which would take some seconds. This command is cloning my whole repo which is taking one hour to download. My brach is `mv_LookbookAddition` it fetches that one as well, seems to work, as it's not merged with master, but I don't want anything else other than my `mv_LookbookAddition` branch to be pulled.

Comment: @nicoX cloning a single branch means getting all the commits accessible from that branch,  all the way to the first one: you can clone only one branch,  but you will get its full history. Again,  everything is working as expected.

Comment: @nicoX You can try (as I explain the edited answer) to add `--depth n`, in order to get only the last `n` commits: that would be closer to what you are looking from.