# Git always bundles annotated tags

Tags: git, backup

I'm having an issue creating backups utilizing [git-bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).

I'm attempting to create backups by running the following list of commands:

```
$git bundle create <path_to_bundle> --all
$last_commit=($(git rev-list --all --timestamp | awk '{print $1+1,$2;exit}'))
$sha_tag=${last_commit[1]}
$timestamp=${last_commit[0]}
$git tag -f lastBundle $sha_tag
```

I then want to verify that when I run this script immediately again over this same repo, that I won't generate a bundle. I run the following:

```
$git bundle create <path_to_bundle> --since=lastBundle --all
```

The problem is this creates a bundle with all of my annotated tags. All other tags and branches are not included, as I would suspect. When I run this command:

```
$git rev-list --since=lastBundle--all
```

I see no commits, but somehow the bundle routine is still picking up my annotated tags.  What am I missing? The most current commit is on a branch, and not on master.

I'm running:

```
 $git version
 git version 1.8.5.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should not be the case since [commit c9a42c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9a42c4a12cec17e858b76d6c68aa17c12c0aef1) (git 1.6.2, Jan. 2009), although that commit has a bug fixed in [commit 2c8544a (git 2.1.1, Aug 2014)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c8544ab91812c264666c9feb335ce3091fa29c1).

So the first test and [update git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I'll update and see if the problem goes away.  I want to pull in annotated tags, but the next time I bundle it shouldn't pick them up.

Comment: I tested version git 2.5.0 using some example repos, and it correctly refuses to re-bundle annotated tags before the lastBundle tag.  This is a bug that has been fixed in later versions.