# Added git branch to bash prompt, now it can't find the start of the command

Tags: bash, prompt

I added the git branch to my bash command line according to the method in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35218509/19776334.

My .bashrc file contains the following lines:

```
parse_git_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/[\1] /'
}

PS1="\[${COLOR_LIGHT_RED}\]\d \t \[${COLOR_GREEN}\] \[\$(parse_git_branch)\]\[${COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE}\]\w \[${COLOR_YELLOW}\]>> \[${COLOR_NC}\]"
```

It looks the way I want, but sometimes I get strange behavior. If I scroll up to a long command I had previously entered and press Home, the cursor goes to the middle of the branch name. If I then try typing, some of the command disappears.

I changed parse_git_branch to

```
    parse_git_branch() {
    echo
    }
```

Then there was no problem with the column. I'm sure this isn't the right way to write in bash. I just wanted to keep the function but return an empty string.

Comment: I don't understand _**replace** the **definition** of parse_git_branch with "echo"_. Please edit your question so that we can see how the working code looks like.

Comment: Aside from this, I would check the output of your function to see, whether it contains some non-printable ASCII characters (i.e. do a  `parse_git_branch|xxd`).

Comment: Although you're getting the problem after adding the branch name to your prompt, this is a basic bash item that has nothing to do with Git itself. I snipped the irrelevant tags...

Comment: I edited the question to make the replace-definition more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is what you'd get if `readline` mis-counts the column positions.  The `\[ ... \]` sequences in `PS1` tell readline that the characters output here are "invisible" (take up no screen columns), so you only want to use them *when the characters are actually invisible*.

Let's look at your `PS1` setting, breaking it into parts:

> ```
> PS1="\[${COLOR_LIGHT_RED}\]
> ```

This is good and right, because (presumably) the `${COLOR_LIGHT_RED}` variable expands to a color-changing sequence that takes no display columns.

> ```
> \d \t \[${COLOR_GREEN}\]
> ```

This, too, seems all good-and-right: \d and \t give the date and time, and do take up columns.  The spaces, including the one after the switch to green color, do as well.

> ```
> \[\$(parse_git_branch)\]
> ```

Uh oh!  The parsed git branch is printed, and takes up columns, when there's a parsed branch.  This *should be counted*.

> ```
> \[${COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE}\]\w \[${COLOR_YELLOW}\]>> \[${COLOR_NC}\]"
> ```

The rest looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and thorough answer. Now it works the way I wanted.